# gitignore file type within root directory only

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

I'm trying to ignore all `.log` file types (ie `foo.log`) in the repository root directory ONLY.

Both `*.log` and `/*.log` match all files of that type within the root directory, but they also match recursively (ie `/foo/bar/baz.log`)

Note: I'm using git on windows (git extensions)

How do I match all files with a specific file type within the repository root directory ONLY?

Comment: `/*.log` works fine here (Git 1.7.9.5 on Linux).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3637660/849425

Comment: I think it's a bug related to the .gitignore file preview feature of git extensions. The previewer shows incorrect results. The /*.log, in fact, does work on windows.

Sorry for the bother.

Comment: @AlbertBori, please file a bug against Git Extensions. Last time I did it, the fix was really prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on git extensions:

https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1040