# ignore a particular folder only in .gitignore but allow other folders with same name to be checked in

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore a dist folder at top level of my project, but then I have another dist folder inside my project for my styles, which I want to keep. So keeping a `dist` in `.gitignore` causes both of them to be ignored. What is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude file only from root folder in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637660/how-to-exclude-file-only-from-root-folder-in-git)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have `dist` in your ignore file, all files and folders named `dist` in the same directory as the ignore file and in all subdirectories recursively are ignored.

If you have `dist/` in your ignore file, all folders but not files named `dist` in the same directory as the ignore file and in all subdirectories recursively are ignored.

If you have `/dist` in your ignore file, all files and folders named `dist` in the same directory as the ignore file but not in any subdirectories are ignored.

If you have `/dist/` in your ignore file, the folder but not file named `dist` in the same directory as the ignore file but not in any subdirectories are ignored.

So change `dist` to `/dist/` in your root folder `.gitignore` and you will be fine.

Alternatively if you can also force-add files in a `dist` folder, because as soon as a file is tracked, `.gitignore` is not effective anymore as it is only applied on untracked files.

Answer (score 2):

put a slash at the start in your `.gitignore` file to only ignore the one in that folder

```
/dist
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your project

```
$ git rm --cached /c/projects/yourApp/dist -r
```

Comment: Hello! This question already has an accepted answer. Before looking at answered questions, please consider looking at [unanswered ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) first. If you do, however, have something to add to an answered question, please consider reading other answers thoroughly.