# .gitignore all except README.md - erroneously tracks another README in subdir

Tags: git

I use the following text in .gitignore to ignore everything except some files that I want to track.

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!README.md



# ...even if they are in subdirectories
!*/
```

However, when i `git add -A`, another `README.md` file in one of the subdirectories are also tracked. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[How to exclude file only from root folder in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637660/how-to-exclude-file-only-from-root-folder-in-git)

Following this example and placing it under exceptions should do the trick

Might have to refresh your tracked list using:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

Comment: Changing `!README.md` to `!/README.md` did the trick. Thanks!