# git ignore file but not folder with the same name

Tags: git, gitignore

My code structure is:

```
.gitignore
my-service << this is a file without an extention
charts
| my-service << this is a folder
| | file1
| | file2
```

When I write in my gitignore `my-service` it ignores both my-service the file and `my-service` the folder.
How can I ignore only the file in the root directory, and not the sub-directory?

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful : 
https://www.2brightsparks.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=10067

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude file only from root folder in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637660/how-to-exclude-file-only-from-root-folder-in-git)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can do the reverse way with`!` in .gitignore

```
myservice
!myservice/
```